# I want to call a particular code before another code run

Tags: angularjs

I have a call in controller

```
vm=this;
User.query()
  .$promise
  .then(function(resp){
    `vm.response = resp` 
  });
```

in if

```
if(!!$stateParams.id){`console.log(vm.response.id);`
}
```

For edit page I got id undefined. User.query get called after this if.
For create it works ok.

Comment: What's with the backticks?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: yes seams to be duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: You can use $stateChangeStart for that.

Comment: @Phil backsticks are a ES6 feature to define multiline strings.

Comment: @Luxor001 yes, I know that but they don't make sense where OP is using them. I assume they just messed up trying to format the code in the question but was confused because it's only applied to those two lines. Will need OP to clean it up

Comment: Ah i see, yeah i agree with you, probably OP messed up the code

Comment: hi, I'm new on stack overflow, I don't get what is OP